# App crashes when Crashlytics started

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I use Crashlytics in my game. I created signed APK and downloaded it in my device with help USB.
App is crashing with error when i start it

```
12-26 09:30:58.263: D/AndroidRuntime(29865): Shutting down VM
12-26 09:30:58.263: W/dalvikvm(29865): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430ef140)
12-26 09:30:58.263: D/KeyguardViewMediator(830): setHidden false
12-26 09:30:58.263: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(830): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
12-26 09:30:58.263: E/AndroidRuntime(29865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 09:30:58.263: E/AndroidRuntime(29865): Process: com.arsanima.game.chapaev, PID: 29865
12-26 09:30:58.263: E/AndroidRuntime(29865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arsanima.game.chapaev/com.arsanima.game.chapaev.AndroidLauncher}: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
12-26 09:30:58.263: E/AndroidRuntime(29865): This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
12-26 09:30:58.263: E/AndroidRuntime(29865): install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
```

Debug build works without errors.
Help please. What do i make incorrect?

Comment: Weird that it works in debug but not release... are you using the same account/key for both? What happens if you disable ProGuard on your release build?

Comment: Yes, i use the same account/key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crashlytics does a lot of work when built in release mode to try to give you un-obfuscated stack traces. Make sure you have configured it completely in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.14.7'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}
```

Comment: I use new version Fabric.io. I took all settings on official site

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - if you're looking for the Fabric specific setup on Gradle, just go here: https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle

Comment: How to configure if you have flavors?